# What is fastest algorithm or method displaying line images from line scan camera

Tags: c++, algorithm

We have a line scan camera which produces 300 line images per second. We want to display the lines on a image view in the way of FIFO so that the last line of the view displays the most recent line image while shifting previous lines above for the line update.

If I can access video memory in C like old days, I would just do

```
memcpy(videoMem, videoMem+lineWidth*pixelSize, pixelSize*lineWidth*(nLines-1));
memcpy(videoMem+pixelSize*lineWidth*(nLines-1),newLine,lineWidth*pixelSize);
```

But I don't know if this is the best I can do even with direct video memory access.

Now I understand it's not possible nor desirable to access video memory directly. In that case, what is the best method? Any opinion from expert would be appreciated.

It is Desktop PC Application in Windows 7.

**Update**

As I expected, It seems that I have to deal with a kind of circular buffers. Tricky part in my case is that writing the buffer is line-by-line while reading is screen-by-screen. So `end` pointer reaches physical end of the buffer, additional memory copy is needed to pass the screen memory into video. I guess Bip buffer would be a solution for this. Any other idea?

Comment: Some more info about your environment would be good. Windows GUI application? Output on the screen of some niche embedded device?

Comment: do you want to use memmove instead of memcpy?  probably doesn't make a difference, but it may depending on the library.

Comment: usually video memory doesn't like to be read (http://www.gapidraw.com/docs/gapidraw/videohw.htm, http://www.gamedev.net/topic/388869-whats-the-difference-between-these-2-things/, etc. etc.).  it's usually quite slow.  what you want to do is to create a buffer in system memory.  operate on that to create a scrolling back buffer.  every time you add a new line, just do a memory write to the video memory frame buffer.  this may be faster.  when you do memcpy/memmove as you have, it does a read and a write on video memory.  the read will hog a lot of time.

Comment: @thang I was afraid of that. Since 99.9% of the new image is the previous image, I hoped there is an quicker way to update the view.

Comment: are you using a library to operate on video ram?  most likely the library gives you the option to do video memory move without having to do a memcpy.. i.e. without going through the cpu.

Comment: @thang I didn't select any library yet as I want to first understand necessary algorithms. Anyway thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot memcpy memory that is overlapping, that is the purpose of memmove. Nevertheless, you can use memcpy as long as the copy occurs in the right order. Try it on your platform to see if it works.

The main implementation issue is if having two separate writes causes flicker. If this is the case, you have to write the new image to a buffer first and then write the entire buffer all at once to the video memory.

Generally speaking you don't read video memory. The data to be displayed should be in its own region of memory. Summing up you have 3 areas of memory:

1. data to be displayed
2. display buffer
3. video memory (or its equivalent)

The standard process is to write 1->2, then 2->3 in one step. If you have no flicker, however, you can go directly 1->3 with no buffer. Other than this, there is no magic algorithm beyond what you have written

Comment: i think that usually (2) and (3) are both in video memory.  they're typically called front and back surfaces.  there is no copy from 2->3.  2->3 is usually a buffer swap (pageflip) that requires no copy.

Comment: remark also that on some video cards it is possible to do a scrolling front buffer where you slide the front buffer along 1 line at a time.  however, when you reach the very end, a copy still needs to be done.  i don't know if there is a video card that does circular front buffer on a line basis.

Comment: @Thomas I am working on a nearly identical application (albeit, scanning at between 1500 and 3000Hz, using C++/Qt, and running on a real-time Linux kernel).  You accepted this question... were you able to implement a solution?  Can you give any guidance/examples of the algorithm?  I'm a C++ novice, but coming up to speed quickly.